# Remove <a> inside <h2> and use the text to fill a <p>

Tags: jquery

I have this Bootstrap snippet:

```
<h2>My Records <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add new</a></h2>
<p></p>
```

I'd like to remove the `<a>` tag from the `<h2>`, keeping only the "naked" text ("My Records") for filling the `<p>` tag, thus resulting this:

```
<h2>My Records <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add new</a></h2>
<p>My Records</p>
```

I made this fiddle but it gets the wrong result: http://jsfiddle.net/3fptd/1/

1. the `<a>` tag is removed from the `<h2>` in the output page
2. the `<p>` is filled with "Add new" text instead of "My Records"

Please, any help?
Thank you!

Comment: `header = $( "h2" ).find( "a" ).remove().end().text();` ??? http://jsfiddle.net/3fptd/4/  But what you are describing is not what you seem to looking for, quite unclear question imho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the contents of the first child of `h2` so try

```
$("p").text(function () {
    return $("h2").prop('firstChild').nodeValue;
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DkSLs/)

Comment: Thanks, this is very wise and I can use it also on markup like <h2>My Header <small>my subheader</small></h2>

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `<a>`'s text instead of the `<h2>`'s.

Corrected version:

```
$( "p" ).text(function(){
    var h2 = $( "h2" );
    h2.find( "a" ).remove();
    return h2.text();
});
```

Corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3fptd/2/

Answer (score 1):

Check out this

```
$( "p" ).text(function(){
    header = $( "h2" ).find( "a" ).remove();
    return $( "h2" ).text();    
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chetangawai/3fptd/5/

Answer (score 0):

You got `<a>` removed becouse method remove delete the full element. That is what you were doing:

1. Get the text of `<a>` element.
2. Delete `<a>` element.

I think that's you asking for...

```
$( "p" ).text(function(){
    var header = $("h2").text().split("Add new");
    return header[0];    
})
```